# Problems with column names in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to use the "write.csv" command to write a csv file in R. Unfortunately, when I do this, the resulting data frame produces colnames with a prefix X in it eventhough the file already has a column name.

It produces, X_name1 ,X_name2

Please kindly tell me your suggestions

I have added an example code similar to my data.

```
a<- c("1","2")
b <- c("3","4")
df <- rbind(a,b)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- c("11_a","12_b")
write.csv(df,"mydf.csv")
a <- read.csv("mydf.csv")
a

#Result
   X X11_a X12_b
1 a     1     2
2 b     3     4
```

All I need is to have only "11_a" and "12_b" as column names. But it incudes prefix X also.

Comment: Showing your code and data will help. Do your column names start with a numeral?

Comment: just do `write.csv(..., col.names=T)`. From the docs (try `?write.csv` on R prompt) "col.names: either a logical value indicating whether the column names of x are to be written along with x, or a character vector of column names to be written. See the section on ‘CSV files’ for the meaning of col.names = NA."

Comment: Yes. It starts with a numeral.

Comment: I used col.names=T, but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `check.names=FALSE` when reading your data back in - names starting with numbers are not generally acceptable in R:

```
read.csv(text="11_a,12_b
a,1,2
b,3,4", check.names=FALSE)

#  11_a 12_b
#a    1    2
#b    3    4

read.csv(text="11_a,12_b
a,1,2
b,3,4", check.names=TRUE)

#  X11_a X12_b
#a     1     2
#b     3     4
```

Comment: beat me on that... now for the poster try with `names(df) <- c("a11","b12")` and `check.names = F` when reading the csv file to see the difference. Basically, R does not like column names starting with numerics. From the man page "check.names : logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are, and also to ensure that there are no duplicates."

Comment: @ thelatemail ..Thank you very much. It works :) . I typed a<- read.csv("mydf.csv",check.names = F).

Comment: @John Smith. Thank you. It works for this data. But I can't use this names(df) for my original data as it has many columns.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is add `header=TRUE` to your code when you read in the .csv file. It would look like:

```
a <- read.csv("mydf.csv", header=TRUE)
```